# Plot gaussian distribution over density of prices return under R

Tags: r, statistics, probability, gaussian

I am trying to overview if prices return have a so-called "fat-tailed" property. Unfortunately, my superposition of my gaussian curve and my return curve doesnot match.

To do that, I have a return vector:

```
data.ret
```

I carried the density, the mean, and the standard deviation of my vector:

```
data.sd <- sd(data.ret)
data.mean <- mean(data.ret)
data.density <- density(data.ret)
```

thus, I am able to find the gaussian distribution within my data.ret properties:

```
data.gauss <- dnorm(data.ret, data.mean, data.sd)
```

Then I plot my results:

```
plot(data.density, xlab="Return", ylab="", yaxt="n", main="Density of returns")
lines(data.ret , data.gauss, type="l",col="red",lwd=1,lty=3)
```

However, my gaussian curve does not look good, I suppose that I wrongly plot my gaussian distribution to fit with my return density:
[image]

EDIT :

if I sort values of data.ret :

[image]

Comment: Agree that using lines with an unordered pair of values is the typical cause of such a jumbled plot. Suspect this is an often repeated question on SO. The "duplicate" was found with a search of "[r] plot lines mess"

Comment: I have just tried, but it does not look like anything gaussian : (

Comment: Maybe the distribution is not Normal. Post the data if you want to ask a question that was different than "why is my plot a mess". I'll retract my close vote if there is data and a different question.

Comment: Even though that data.ret may not be gaussian, 
data.density is gaussian, since it is gaussian distribution with a mean and a standard deviation of data.ret

Comment: Thanks 李哲源 , it works perfectly

Comment: Sorry 42- for the misleading answer.